# plupload, custom, simple UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I've just started using plupload and i want its look to be consistent with my page. 
Here it is how it looks like by default:

[image]

But I need a much more simple UI because i have to upload just one file. Moreover, my page already contains instructions for the user on how to upload so I don't want plupload to show its own.
So I need:

1. a single button in order to select and start the upload
2. a drag area as alternative way of file choice
3. a progress bar

Perhaps i shouldn't use the provided UI, but in such case i don't know how to manage the progress bar and the drag area. 
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at their CSS (https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css) and you can either override the classes / properties needed or create your own based on that and ditch theirs. The second is cleaner but require more attention to details to not fail to cover some use cases.

Comment: There is a different CSS file for the queue here https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css

Comment: I would start from the core example http://plupload.com/examples/core setting the drop_element option to enable drag/drop. Enable chunking to have progression, and implement the ChunkUploaded event to update progress bar. (Sorry, no time to elaborate)